# C# KVP Sorting - Modify sorting

Tags: c#, sorting

I have a series of KVP their values might look like this

```
[month],[January]
[year],[1990]
[month],[April]
[year],[2001]
[month],[February]
[year],[1991]
[month],[February]
[year],[1992]
[month],[April]
[year],[2002]
[month],[March]
[year],[2000]
```

They need to be sorted like this

```
[month],[January]
[month],[April]
[month],[February]
[month],[February]
[month],[April]
[month],[March]
[year],[1990]
[year],[2001]
[year],[1991]
[year],[1992]
[year],[2002]
[year],[2000]
```

This is the sort function

```
 indexValuesToCountOnce.Sort((x, y) => x.Value.Length.CompareTo(y.Value.Length));
```

However I am finding the code to be unpredictable for me. It seems to first order the months column by the length of the string month, not the order it was in the kvp.

Is there a way to sort this in the way I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you just want an alphabetical sort on the key:

```
list = x.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Key).ToList();
```

Comment: Haveing issues, could it be because of how my list is defined?
`code`
    List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> indexValuesToCountOnce = new      List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

Comment: @Krom That should work fine. Just replace `x` in my code with `indexValuesToCountOnce` and put `var` in front of `list`.

Comment: This requires using System.Linq; I beleive. I am not in Visual Studio so I cannot just add a reference

Comment: @Krom Yes, it requires LINQ. Just add `using System.Linq;` to the top of your .cs file.

Comment: I had to add some other ones for some reason as well, I feel like when I added the reference and the "using" it didn't take. Either way after some fidgeting it works! Thank you!